# PHP - include index.php for path above this one

Tags: php, filesystems, include

So, am using this code here...

```
<?php

if (file_exists(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/index.php'))
    include(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/index.php');
else
    exit;

?>
```

So I have a filepath like so:

> /root/folder/a_sub1/b_sub1/c_sub1/d_sub1

Each *_sub folder has a file `index.php` with the above code in it. The **folder** directory has the following code in its index.php file.

```
<?php

// Look for Settings.php....
if (file_exists(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/Settings.php'))
{
    // Found it!
    require(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/Settings.php');
    header('Location: ' . $boardurl);
}
// Can't find it... just forget it.
else
    exit;

?>
```

The **root** folder has Settings.php within it that defines the `$boardurl` to be:  `http://dptest.dream-portal.net`, so why is it NOT redirecting to the `$boardurl` when I type in the url like this?

`http://dptest.dream-portal.net/folder/a_sub1`

To my understanding, it should include each index.php file within each path above it, until it gets to **folder** and than it should call upon Settings.php within the root and this should than just load up the `$boardurl` (http://dptest.dream-portal.net) instead right?  Makes sense to me, but instead I am getting a 500 Internal Server Error when browsing any subdirectories within the **folder** directory...

Can someone please help me here.

Cheers :)

Comment: Check your code for errors outside of what you've included above. I tried it w my system and it worked. --- I would start with going directly to `settings.php` and seeing what the variables are there and that the page loads... then go to the next index.php down, first just print out something to the screen, then try to use settings.php to redirect... etc.

Comment: Ok, so I am seeing that some sub-directories work while others don't.  This doesn't make any sense to me, for example:  `http://www.mydomain.com/folder/a_sub1` works, `http://www.mydomain.com/folder/a_sub1/b_sub1` does NOT work and gives me a 500 Internal Server Error, and `http://www.mydomain.com/folder/a_sub1/b_sub1/c_sub1` works and redirects to http://www.mydomain.com.  I don't get it?  How can 1 sub-directory not work, but the sub-directories within the non-working one, work??  Doesn't make any sense to me!

Comment: check the error log when you have the error 500 and add _once in your include and require instructions, to prevent multiple inclusions of the same file (just in case of)

Comment: Nevermind, all of a sudden it is working.  Adding in the _once suffix ruined all paths to cause a 500 Error.